# How do I detect a copy event in Finder?

Tags: terminal, osx, copy-paste

I am trying to strip formatting from text copied from my Illustrator docs. Someone accurately pointed out to me that running `pbpaste | pbcopy` via command-line will perform this action on text in the clipboard, but obviously it's not ideal to run this every time I copy something from Illustrator.

Is there a way to detect this event and then fire it off every time something in the system is copied via a shell script?